Can you/Would it be a good idea to fry with fat pieces instead of tallow?
Im currently frying with a lot of tallow but it is on the expensive side.  I have seen fat cubes for a lot cheaper.
This got me thinking why don’t I just fry some fat cubes in a little bit of fat, the tallow will come out and I’ll immediately be able to use rendered tallow for frying.
This should make it significantly cheaper but also save me from having to make and store my own tallow.  Cons I can think of is that I’ll still have to discard fat cubes and do a little bit extra cooking each time I fry.
Is there any other cons about doing this?  I haven’t tried it yet but I’m just thinking would you have to thaw the fat first since it would be from the freezer or is this not an issue you can add it direct, also perhaps bits of fat pieces will shred off/have meat in it so you will be left with a sauce that’s look unfiltered?
Thanks

Do you mind your cooking taking longer? It will take some time for the fat to render. Repeated many time with such small quantities will add up, and be much less efficient than rendering a large amount at once and storing the result for immediate use. | In another post you mention something like 5:1 ratio by mass -- even if it's not so bad, it would still seem more efficient to store the result rather than the raw ingredient.

There's no problem doing what you propose. It works, and can be very tasty. It's rarely done in modern Western cooking (where animal fat is rarely used anyway), but it's used in some recipes with bacon.
One difference you'll get is taste. When you make greaves (the technical term for cubes of fat after the frying process), you get a pronounced bacon-like taste that's not there when you render tallow gently in water. The taste is present in both the greaves and the rendered grease, even if you start with cubes that are very low in meat.
Also, you have to find out what kind of fat cubes you are getting. If they are raw, that's all there is to it. If you're getting cured cubes (salo), they are quite salty, and this salt is going to be very noticeable in the dish.
Else, it's even easier than you imagined it. You can just throw the cubes into the pan, without any "starter" fat, they won't stick. Just wait with the other ingredients until there is some rendered liquid grease in the pan. And afterwards, you don't have to remove the cubes either, just eat them along with the rest of the dish. They get a crispy outer skin and are really tasty.

I doubt you will get raw fat sold at a butcher shop. Outside that present on meat. What gets sold as fat in shops will almost always be rendered.
